# Access DOM in render() of React (v15)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, document, getelementsbytagname

While I study React, I found the following code.

As far as I understand, DOM in React is usually accessed via *Refs*.

However, this code uses *document*, and I haven't seen any one uses this way.

Do I misunderstand? Is this formal way?

Plus, *document.form* is same with *document.getElementByTagName("form")*?

Any reference would be helpful.

```
    export default class IssueAdd extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = document.forms.issueAdd;
        this.props.createIssue({
            owner: form.owner.value,
            title: form.title.value,
            status: 'New',
            created: new Date(),
        });
        form.owner.value = '';
        form.title.value = '';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form name="issueAdd" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" name="owner" placeholder="Owner" />
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
                    <button>Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is just another javascript library, so it has all the powers that you might have used in a plain javascript like, access to *window* object or *document* object.
But does that mean you should use them, absolutely NO and [you will find the reasons here](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/the-difference-between-virtual-dom-and-dom/). Direct DOM manipulation is very costly operation.

Basically, React works on the concept of [virtual DOM](https://hackernoon.com/virtual-dom-in-reactjs-43a3fdb1d130). Virtual DOM makes it way too **easy and faster** for React to update the actual DOM, without going over the overhead of multiple direct DOM manipulations.

Coming to refs, since we don't want to access a HTML element using *document* object React provided Refs, which will help to get into a specific element and access it quickly (it will return data from virtual DOM).

Couple of good articles on refs:

- http://jamesknelson.com/react-js-by-example-interacting-with-the-dom/
- https://hackernoon.com/refs-in-react-all-you-need-to-know-fb9c9e2aeb81

and off course

- https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

> BTW: Welcome to the wonderful world of React :)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the DOM over the document variable is not the recommended way in React.

As you said, you should create a reference for your element and access it over that. (More about refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

---

Short example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  getOffset = () => {
    console.log(this.myRef.current.offsetTop); // will output the offset top of the div
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} onClick={this.getOffset}>Test div</div>;
  }
}
```

This will console log the offset top of the div on click.

---

Info: `React.createRef()` was added in React 16.3, before that you had callback Refs - more about that in the docs...

Comment: The question is about v15, it would be helpful to get an example from you, instead of pointing to the docs.